# What is the user defined action "type" for?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, first-responder

What does the "type" column do here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add arbitrary actions that you can bind on the first responder. Actions are of the form:

```
- (IBOutlet)someAction:(id)sender
```

The sender is the UI element that caused that action to be called.

However, it can be nicer to have a type there, so if you're only going to wire buttons to this action, you could set the type to `UIButton` and then you'd make the method like this.

```
- (IBOutlet)someAction:(UIButton *)sender
```

Comment: But no parameters apart from the sender?

Comment: Correct. Target/action can only pass the sender and (optionally) the event that generated the action. I've very rarely used that second option, and I don't know if IB supports it for first responder custom actions (the last time I created a new first responder action, IB was still a separate program from Xcode, so it's been a little while :D)